# Is there any way to create validation function in system_settings_form

Tags: 7, forms

Creating a form having two file type element, i want to check that if user uploaded file any file, then user must upload both file, so is there any way to add a validate function in system_settings_form.

Comment: As a side note, you may want to read through this, https://www.drupal.org/node/635046.  The last time I tried to use two files on a setting form, I ran into this bug,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `system_settings_form` should be used to set simple variables for your module, see the approved answer and related comment here:

[Is "system_settings_form" voodoo?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49034/is-system-settings-form-voodoo#comment50658_49036)

If you want to be sure both form fields are filled out during submission you don't need a validate function -- you can set both fields as being required when you create your form array:

```
$form['SOMETHING']['#required'] = TRUE;
```

where *something* is your form field key.

If you have complex logic and your form isn't simply setting a configuration variable you will call with `variable_get` or `variable_set` later -- then implement a custom `form_validate` and `form_submit` function for your form as your form is not simply a variable settings form.

See the [Form API Handbook](https://www.drupal.org/node/37775). Also of use is this [drupal `$form` lifecycle or workflow illustration](https://www.drupal.org/node/165104). Lastly [form validation helpers and submit handlers](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/form_api/7) are touched on briefly on this page of the handbook.

**EDIT:**

Just to complete my answer, hook_form_alter can change many aspects of a form used by drupal.

**EDIT 2:**

You can add a custom validator on the form you use to build `return system_settings_form($form);` for an example see the Commerce Admin include file here: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce/tree/includes/commerce_ui.admin.inc

They set:

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'commerce_currency_settings_form_validate';
```

in their form builder function then they provide a validation function:

```
/**
 * Form validate handler for the currency settings form.
 */
function commerce_currency_settings_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // Ensure the default currency is always enabled.
  $default = $form_state['values']['commerce_default_currency'];
  $form_state['values']['commerce_enabled_currencies'][$default] = $default;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I can't make that element a  required field because form also having other element but i can do it with form alter or i just check my condition in submit handler, i Just wanna know that there is no such term (validate) in system_settings_form

Comment: please see my second Edit which I hope answers your question.